# Firebase is showing permission denied even if the action is successfully achieved

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Firebase is showing me the message from bellow at login and when I am trying to add a new element in the database, but still the actions are completed. The data are arriving in Firestore, my user is logged in, but the in the console I receive these messages about permission denied.

```
index.cjs.js:15024 Uncaught (in promise) Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied
    at index.cjs.js:15024
    at exceptionGuard (index.cjs.js:798)
    at Repo.callOnCompleteCallback (index.cjs.js:15013)
    at index.cjs.js:14771
    at index.cjs.js:13825
    at PersistentConnection.onDataMessage_ (index.cjs.js:13875)
    at Connection.onDataMessage_ (index.cjs.js:13007)
    at Connection.onPrimaryMessageReceived_ (index.cjs.js:13000)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (index.cjs.js:12879)
    at WebSocketConnection.appendFrame_ (index.cjs.js:12407)
    at WebSocketConnection.handleIncomingFrame (index.cjs.js:12468)
    at WebSocket.mySock.onmessage (index.cjs.js:12340)
(anonymous) @ index.cjs.js:15024
exceptionGuard @ index.cjs.js:798
Repo.callOnCompleteCallback @ index.cjs.js:15013
(anonymous) @ index.cjs.js:14771
(anonymous) @ index.cjs.js:13825
PersistentConnection.onDataMessage_ @ index.cjs.js:13875
Connection.onDataMessage_ @ index.cjs.js:13007

Connection.onPrimaryMessageReceived_ @ index.cjs.js:13000
(anonymous) @ index.cjs.js:12879
WebSocketConnection.appendFrame_ @ index.cjs.js:12407
WebSocketConnection.handleIncomingFrame @ index.cjs.js:12468
mySock.onmessage @ index.cjs.js:12340
index.cjs.js:15024 Uncaught (in promise) Error: PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied
    at index.cjs.js:15024
    at exceptionGuard (index.cjs.js:798)
    at Repo.callOnCompleteCallback (index.cjs.js:15013)
    at index.cjs.js:14876
    at index.cjs.js:13750
```

Those are my rules in Firestore:

```
// Allow read/write access on all documents to any user signed in to the application
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your security rules require that an authenticated user make the query.  The error message is suggesting that you didn't perform the query while a user was signed in.  Your code should wait until a user is signed in before making a query.  Usually do do that with an [auth state observer](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data).